# Mockito - mock builder returns a null object even when returns_self is used

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I have created a test for Notifications in Android and am struggling with making Mock objects. When I try to Mock the `notificationBuilder` following [this post(which suggests wrapping Android notifications in a custom class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334429/how-to-make-android-unit-test-for-notifications) I get a null `notificationBuilder`, which then ruins my tests.

My minimal code showing this is:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = Mockito.mock(NotificationCompat.Builder.class, Mockito.RETURNS_SELF);
}
```

where notificationBuilder is null. How can I get a Mock NotificationCompat.Builder as the return value? I thought this was what `RETURNS_SELF` was supposed to do.

With a null value I can't use my Builder as part of a when().then() for further testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Mockito.mock(...)` is returning `null` because you aren't mocking anything. You need to declare a global variable with the `@Mock` annotation and initialize your mock object in the `setUp()` method(you can call this anything as long as it has the `@Before` annotation on it). Try the below code snippet.

```
    @Mock
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        notificationBuilder = Mockito.mock(NotificationCompat.Builder
                .class);

    }
   @Test
    public void testSharedPrefInjection(){

        assertNotNull(notificationBuilder);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are creating a mock which in the end is a local variable inside the `@Before` method.

When you later run your tests this variable is not accessible anymore, nor there is any notion of a global mock for a class (at least in vanilla Mockito).

So either use a global variable which you then initialize manually in the setUp method:

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;

@Before
public void setUp() {
   notificationBuilder = Mockito.mock(NotificationCompat.Builder.class);
}
```

or use Mockito annotations:

```
@Mock
private NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;

@Before
public void setUp() {
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```